# Make: Avoiding issues from having same targets in multiple Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to know the best way of dealing with this. Also you could answer this -- after reading the sample below --: Look at the `makelib` target in `package.make` and tell me if there is a way to force this be treated as not updated if the recipe (make -C ../lib/ -f lib.make) reports as nothing to be made (not using ordered prequisites)?

I need to explain this point using an example. I have inherited this and I need the best way to make this right.

A target which other targets will be depending on:

```
File lib.make
--------------
.DEFAULT_GOAL = thelib.dll

%.dll: file1.obj file2.obj
      makelib file1.obj file2.obj -o thelib.dll
```

This by itself is pretty solid. You run it once (`make -f lib.make`) and it creates the lib. If you run it subsequently, having no modified files, then it will tell you it has nothing to do.

Now we're going to use this in a special way somewhere else:

```
File: package.make
------------------
.DEFAULT_GOAL: all

all: package

makelib: 
        @make -C ../lib/ -f lib.make

package: makelib file3 file4
        @package_files file3 file4 ../lib/out/*.dll -o package
```

This is how `lib.make` is referenced inside `package.make`.

The issue is even though the package gets created when you call `make -f package.make all` make assumes that `package` target needs to be rebuilt every time since one of its dependencies -- `makelib` -- had to be remade

Make considers `makelib` out of date despite what happens after entering `lib.make`.

To correct this I thought of a few choices:

- moving `makelib` to the ordered prerequisites ( after the `|`) but that's not quite right because in case of a newly built library my package wont' be updated
- adding the dll (`thelib.dll`) as the dependency to the `makelib` target a second time but this would almost duplicate the logic and break the encapsulation.
- removing `makelib` target and moving the line `@make -C ../lib/ -f lib.make` to inside the `package` recipe. There is a problem with this and that is that I have removed the dependency between the package and lib. If lib requires update, the package won't know about it and won't get updated.
- using `include lib.make` and then rewriting `package` rule to something like: `package: thelib.dll file3 file4`. There are problems with this also and the least of them is for a make file to be included, it must be written as such. Otherwise a lot of overwriting/conflicting targets and definitions will be introduced.

Are there any suggestions other than  and directly listing the dll as the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways this works:

First, if you use recursive make (please remember to always invoke a sub-make using `$(MAKE)`, never `make` directly) then you should make the target in the parent makefile be the actual file generated by the sub-make:

```
package: lib/thelib.dll ...
         ...

lib/thelib.dll: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -f lib
FORCE:
```

Second, you can use non-recursive make which means you include the sub-makefile into the parent make and write it so that it expects that.  You can play tricks with variables etc. to make this more generic, so it can be invoked from either the parent or subdirectory, if you want.

Comment: Isn't having `FORCE` like marking `lib/thelib.dll` as PHONY? meaning it will always be updated regardless of it being uptodate or not? Which will cause `package` to always execute also?

Comment: It's "like" it, but not the same as.  If you used `.PHONY` then two things will be true: (a) the recipe will always be run (we want this) and (b) the target `lib/thelib.dll` will always be considered out of date--we don't want this because it means that `package` will always be rebuilt even if `lib/thelib.dll` didn't actually change.  By using the `FORCE` trick we still get (a) because `FORCE` doesn't exist, but then the mod time on `lib/thelib.dll` is used to determine if it was updated or not rather than assuming it was always updated.

Comment: Really creative. It definitely works. I just need to take time to digest it fully

Comment: It's based on a long-standing, but not necessarily well-known, feature of make: if make decided to build a target and run a recipe it does not simply assume that the target was updated.  Make will check the modification time after the recipe finishes to see if the target was really changed.  If it wasn't, then make doesn't consider it updated when determining whether targets that depend on it need to be updated.  This feature is used _constantly_ for more advanced makefile operations.

Comment: I think i understand it a lot better after running this a few times with -d. It's almost genius. Since the access timestamp of the dll does not change then we're updating package. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Just to be clear, make looks at the modification timestamp of files, not the access timestamp.  But otherwise, you got it.